# Spring security OAuth2 Resource server JWT authorization error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/message/**").hasRole("test-role")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new RoleMapper());
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static class RoleMapper implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            final Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = (Map<String, Collection<String>>) jwt.getClaims().get("realm_access");
            return realmAccess.get("roles").stream()
                    .map(roleName -> "ROLE_" + roleName)
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
@Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get("/message")
                        .with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_test_role"))))
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).as("Response has incorrect HTTP status.").isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
```

Logs

```
2021-08-31 09:28:12.862 TRACE 119643 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /message] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_test-role')]
2021-08-31 09:28:12.866 TRACE 119643 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
2021-08-31 09:28:12.866 TRACE 119643 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /message] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_test-role')] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2503ec73], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
2021-08-31 09:28:12.867 TRACE 119643 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2021-08-31 09:28:12.868 TRACE 119643 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@bbd01fb9, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_test_role]] to access denied handler since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
```

Spring boot version - 2.5.4
Why does the WebExpressionVoter doesn't resolve the granted authority? What am I missing?(Tried with actual auth server too, same error)
I tested with multiple previous version of spring boot but no joy.
Any advice/recommendations/suggestions please

Comment: I have created a minimal, reproducible sample here
https://github.com/mparthasarathi429/security-demo

Comment: You are adding a prefix in the authority which is already `ROLE_test_role`, like so: `.map(roleName -> "ROLE_" + roleName)`. Can you try getting rid of the "ROLE_" prefix on the `RoleMapper`?.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Tried your suggestion. same error

Comment: Please add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your properties file. Which Spring Boot and Spring Security version are you using?

Comment: Spring boot version - 2.5.4 and spring security - 5.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test you use `ROLE_test_role` and in the security configuration you have `test-role` - one with hyphen, one with underscore. I think that's the problem.

Comment: sigh! Focused on the role prefix and missed role name all together